# How to display Image in React Native with in 2 columns?

Tags: react-native

**how i can display image in 2 colums? now i have 4 images which display vertical and user can click and pop out with close window (x) button.this page also cant scroll .** 
Please someone help with Image display

i want like this

Image 1   Image 2

image 3   Image 4

[my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1fSE.png)

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main}>
       {"\n"}{"\n"}<Text style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>Promotions Coupons</Text>{"\n"}{"\n"}{"\n"}{"\n"}{"\n"}{"\n"}
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
          source={{ uri: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0127/0982/files/SFS1703E-In-Store-Christmas-Coupon_grande.jpg?v=1509547438' }}

        >
        </Image>

         <Image
          style={styles.image}
          style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
          source={{ uri: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0127/0982/files/SFS1703E-In-Store-Christmas-Coupon_grande.jpg?v=1509547438' }}

        >
        </Image>
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
          source={{ uri: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0127/0982/files/SFS1703E-In-Store-Christmas-Coupon_grande.jpg?v=1509547438' }}

        >
        </Image>



          <Text>
          <Text>{ this.addPadding() }</Text>

    <Text>
  <Text style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}></Text>{"\n"}

</Text>      




        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  addPadding() {
    const padding = Array.apply(null, Array(16)).map(() => '').join('');
    return Array.apply(null, Array(8)).map(() => padding + '\n');
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 40,
  },

  image: {
    width: 600,
    height: 110,
    position: 'absolute',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can be dividing the main view into two child View( children)  and each child View will have 2-2 Images. assign flexDirection as row in child View so that the two images will be rendered row-wise along the mainaxis.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
  Image, 
  Text, 
  View, 
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main}>
        <Text style={{fontWeight: "bold",alignSelf:'center', marginBottom:20}}>Promotions Coupons</Text>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', margin:20, justifyContent:"space-between"}}>
          <Image
            style={{width: 100, height: 100, }}
            source={{ uri: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0127/0982/files/SFS1703E-In-Store-Christmas-Coupon_grande.jpg?v=1509547438' }}/>
          <Image
            style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
            source={{ uri: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0127/0982/files/SFS1703E-In-Store-Christmas-Coupon_grande.jpg?v=1509547438' }}/>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', margin:20, justifyContent:"space-between"}}>
          <Image
            style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
            source={{ uri: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0127/0982/files/SFS1703E-In-Store-Christmas-Coupon_grande.jpg?v=1509547438' }}
          />
          <Image
          style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
          source={{ uri: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0127/0982/files/SFS1703E-In-Store-Christmas-Coupon_grande.jpg?v=1509547438' }}
        />
        </View>
        <Text>
          <Text>{ this.addPadding() }</Text>
          <Text>
             <Text style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}></Text>{"\n"}
          </Text>      
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

addPadding() {
    const padding = Array.apply(null, Array(16)).map(() => '').join('');
    return Array.apply(null, Array(8)).map(() => padding + '\n');
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 40,
  },

  image: {
    width: 600,
    height: 110,
    position: 'absolute',
  },
});
```

Comment: Feel free to ask any question